# Deadline exceeded while waiting for HTTP response from URL: HTTPException

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, httplib, httpexception

I'm developing an app to listen for twitter hash tags using **tweepy**. I have uploaded my app to Google App Engine and it's giving me below error.

**Last line of Traceback:**

```
File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/gae_override/httplib.py", line 524, in getresponse
    raise HTTPException(str(e))
HTTPException: Deadline exceeded while waiting for HTTP response from URL: https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json?delimited=length
```

How could I solve this?

Comment: How about you add some of your code here (namely the relevant part)???

Comment: When I try to hit the url, it asks for some authentication. Are you sure you are properly authenticated? this could be why your request hangs for a minute before popping that error.  In any case, as barak manos pointed out... we need some kind of code to see what can be done

Comment: @barakmanos I'm using this [project](https://github.com/KaveenR/SiripalaBot/blob/master/bot.py)

Comment: @Julldar Authentication is ok. I have local `.json` file and i can tweet data on it. Link to code added on above comment.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the default timeout for url fetch, I believe it's set to 5 seconds by default.  That endpoint call might take longer.  Perhaps 30 seconds?

```
urlfetch.fetch(url=url, method=urlfetch.GET, deadline=30)
```

You can go up to 60 per the docs: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/#Python_Fetching_URLs_in_Python

Comment: I have added this line to my script. `urlfetch.set_default_fetch_deadline(45)`. But it's not worked.

Comment: You might need to create appengine_config.py at the root of your project and do that setting there.  That's the python module config (where you can override and set things) on load.  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appengineconfig

Answer (score 0):

I am running a simple app on GAE which interacts with a jenkins CI server, using jenkinsapi library which depends on requests. I am shipping both jenkinsapi as well as requests with my app, requests is not supported on GAE though it exists in Google Cloud SDK where I took it from. 
jenkinsapi sends a sick number of requests to the server, I was getting very often

```
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~jenkins-watcher/v0-1.382631715892564425/libs/requests-2.3.0-py2.7.egg/requests/adapters.py", line 375, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
    ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='XXXXXXX', port=8080):
    Max retries exceeded with url: XXXXXX
    (Caused by <class 'gae_override.httplib.HTTPException'>:
    Deadline exceeded while waiting for HTTP response from URL: XXXXXXXX
```

It turned out that number of retries is 0 and timeout was some very low default. Increasing both numbers, for which I had to patch the library, helped and I am not seeing this problem anymore.

Actually, it still happens, but:

Retrying (3 attempts remain) after connection broken by 'HTTPException('Deadline exceeded while waiting for HTTP response from URL ...